# Google VR View iOS - Seek to the target time position of the video.

Tags: ios, video, google-vr

I am facing some problem while working with GVRVideoView.

I tried to implement an UISlider to show the progress of the video and allowed user to slide and change the desired time of the video. And I had set the maximum value of my slider to the video duration (ex: 10.05).

The issues come from this method:

```
- (void)seekTo:(NSTimeInterval)position;
```

**First Issues:**

When I drag the slider to value, ex: 4.53, I will get this error:

> CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(4.530 seconds, timescale 1): warning: error of
>   -0.530 introduced due to very low timescale

**Second Issues:**
When I hardcoded the position value to 5, 
ex:

`[_videoView seekTo:5];`

the video time goes to 8.43. It does not change according to the value I had set.

Comment: Anyone have same issues?